# Running a .png as .exe in powershell from a .zip

Tags: powershell, cmd, exe, minecraft

I am trying to disguise an executable, and have been encountering some problems, but there's only one that I need help with, I am running this from cmd:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -windowstyle hidden start-process C:\Users\b0nke\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\resourcepacks\§4VotPack§cOverlay.zip\assets\minecraft\textures\items\clock.png
```

you can see that I am trying to run a .png inside of a .zip. But I want to open the .png as an executable, is this even possible?

Extra info: I am able to run a .png as a .exe from cmd, but I am using powershell because it can run files inside of an archive, if I were to run it outside of an archive, it would be this:

```
C:\Users\b0nke\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\resourcepacks\clock.png
```

Please respond with some tips or solutions.

Comment: `%USERNAME%` is for cmd. `$env:USERNAME` is for PowerShell

Comment: Thanks, but would you happen to know how to run a .png as a .exe?

Comment: Windows uses file associations, based on the file's extension. `.png` is normally associated with some graphics editor and is not regarded as [executable](https://aerorock.co.nz/list-of-executable-file-extensions-windows/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems a bit malicious.

Comment: it's not for malicious use, I need to know because I'm developing external modifications for minecraft, and I need to make the file hidden from tools and people who try to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, in PowerShell - sensibly - you *cannot* use a non-executable filename extension such as `.png` to directly execute a file that is an executable (in disguise)** - PowerShell defers to the Windows (GUI) shell, which opens the file with the application registered for the filename extension at hand (which in the case of `.png` is `Photos` by default - which would simply complain about an unrecognized image format).

Incredibly - as you state, by contrast - `cmd.exe` apparently explicitly checks the file format itself before taking action, and directly executes executable files even if they happen to have a non-executable filename extension.

Note:

- Perhaps needless to say, **PowerShell's behavior is preferable from a security standpoint**, as it prevents inadvertent execution of executables by unsuspecting users that justifiably assume that a given file is indeed of the type that its filename extension advertises, not an executable in disguise.

*If you really need this functionality* (it's hard to imagine non-deceptive uses):

In principle, you can  call `cmd.exe`'s *CLI* from PowerShell in order to use the former's functionality; e.g.:

```sh
cmd /c .\clock.png
```

That would only work with file paths that `cmd.exe` understands too, however.

It wouldn't work with a path that targets a file *inside a ZIP archive* - but I'm not aware of that working in PowerShell either, unlike what you state.

Answer (score 0):

its basically the same as run an exe -

`start G:\image.png`

Or

`start $usbDriveLetter"image.png"`

or

`image.png`

you need to change it `$env:USERNAME` instead of `$USERNAME`

Comment: I'm slightly confused, my problem is that I would like to run a .png as an executable. As in for example:
I want C:\image.png to be ran is if it was C:\image.exe, but without renaming it to image.exe

Comment: please explain better @getbonk